# Netlify, socket.io and Node.js not co-operating

Tags: javascript, node.js, netlify

I have a node.js app with socket.io and I would like to deploy it with netlify. But I can't do this without an annoying error:

```
internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:969
   throw err;
   ^
 Error: Cannot find module '/opt/build/repo/index.js'
     at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:966:15)
     at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:842:27)
     at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (internal/modules/run_main.js:71:12)
     at internal/main/run_main_module.js:17:47 {
   code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
   requireStack: []
 }
```

I have a github repo at this link: https://github.com/SupremeButter/multiplayer-snake-game-master

I've tried searching online for answers but the error is too specific for me (A new programmer) to yield any helpful information on google.

Answer (score 0):

this is a error too specific to what you might have done with code. unless you post code image or write what steps did you take to deploy it on netlify,there's no catching the error.

alternate solution,try using heroku. it has a very easy setup

Comment: Sorry this was my bad I forgot to mention it may be a problem with socket.io. I have edited the question.